# Overriding compare operator in Python

Tags: python, overriding, operator-keyword

I'm trying to compare my class to integer. I override the operator:

```
class Cell:

def __init__(self, level, x, y):
    self.level = level
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def __cmp__(self, obj):
    if self.level < obj:
        return -1
    if self.level == obj:
        return 0
    if self.level > obj:
        return 1

def __repr__(self):
    return self.level
```

But when I'm trying to compare

```
A = [[Cell(x * y, x, y) for x in range(5)] for y in range(5)]
print(A[3][3] > 5)
```

I'm getting:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: Cell() > int()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I wanted to add that this only happens in python 3

Comment: Python3 wants you to override `__lt__` etc. instead of `__cmp__`.

Comment: See also https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons